# prototype js typeof value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with Js, has a issue when checking the typeof the value 'true' or 'false'.

```
FormPanelField.prototype._isValidValue = function(value) {
value = value == false ? 'false' : value;
if(typeof value !== 'string') {
    this._lastErrorMessage = "The parameter must be a string.";
    return false;
}
return true;};
```

I call the above function :

> this._isValidValue(value)

The above function checks is the value **string**!! but when I pass a value 'false' as a string the **typeof** fails as it considers as **boolen**. So i made a change to the value before the condition check.

> value = value == false ? 'false' : value;

Is it a standard way to do it or is there any other way to do it.??

Fiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/8zur4jms/1/ (updated)

Comment: Are you talking about a `function` `prototype` or PrototypeJS library?

Comment: why is it down voted :( if people cant understand the question they should ask.

Comment: forget about prototype lits see it in JS as well.

Comment: I've not downvoted the question

Comment: `typeof 'false'` is **not** "boolean". The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: check the fiddle.. @JJJ

Comment: In the fiddle you're passing `false` as a boolean, not as a string.

Comment: @JJJ just updated the question with how i call it as well as in fiddle i made some changes.

Comment: It's really not clear what what you're asking or what the problem is. Your fiddle works as expected: it alerts "hi" because `typeof false` is not "string". If I change it to `value = 'false';` then it alerts "oi" because now `typeof 'false'` *is* "string".

Comment: The problem is that I send the value to the function as string 'false', get the 'false' from an input and sent it through the function. @JJJ but it consider it as FALSE not 'FALSE'

Comment: Well, good luck. I have no idea what you're asking, but maybe someone has better divination skills.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for!

```
FormPanelField.prototype._isValidValue = function (value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' || value !== false) {
        this._lastErrorMessage = "The parameter must be a string.";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```